# How to stop a particular service in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS account, i have created to do some research. I have started some of its services. Now I want to cancel some services like EC2 and RDS. There is an option in Manage Account section for "Cancel Selected Service" but in its dropdown menu, there is nothing to select.

Comment: they should either remove the dropdown or allow to cancel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the instances you are not using any more. Not really sure what it means to cancel a service as billing is usage based.

Answer (score 4):

You can't cancel a service, to my knowledge. All you can do is to stop using it, which will mean zero charges on your credit card.

Comment: when terminating EC2 instances make sure there are neither EBS volumes nor Snapshots left behind.